# Is it possible to have external trigger in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I need a worker to subscribe to new data entries in a column family.
I have to invoke the services consuming data on the producer side, or poll the column family for new data, which is a waste of resources and also leads to some extended latency.

I want some external service to be invoked when new data is written to column family. Is it possible to invoke an external service, such as an REST endpoint upon new data arrival?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two features, [triggers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html) and [CDC](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html) (change data capture) that may work. You can create a trigger to receive updates and execute the http request, or you can use CDC to get a per replica copy of the mutations as a log to walk through.

CDC is better for consistency, since a trigger fires before mutations applied, your API endpoint may be notified but then have the mutation fail to apply so your at an inconsistent state. But triggers are easier since you dont need to worry about deduplication since its only 1 per query vs 1 per replica. Or you can use both, triggers that update a cached state and then CDC with a map reduce job to fix any inconsistencies.